# Centering equations under align

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations, align

I'm trying to display two equations side by side and then display a third one centred between both on the next line. I'm using the `align` environment. Here's what I've tried

```
\begin{align*}
    E_n = \frac{n^2h^2}{8m_{e^{-}}L^2} &   & L=4\times d_{\text{c-c}}=5.64\si{\angstrom}\\
    &E_1 = \frac{1^2h^2}{8m_{e^{-}}5.46^2}&\\
\end{align*}
```

[image: Aligning equations]
How can I correctly display these?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a number of ways of achieving this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,siunitx}

\begin{document}

Using \verb|align*|:
\begin{align*}
  E_n = \frac{n^2h^2}{8m_{e^{-}}L^2} & & L = 4 \times d_{\text{c-c}} = 5.64\si{\angstrom} \\
  & E_1 = \frac{1^2h^2}{8m_{e^{-}}5.46^2}
\end{align*}

Using \verb|gather*| (1):
\begin{gather*}
  E_n = \frac{n^2h^2}{8m_{e^{-}}L^2} \qquad L = 4 \times d_{\text{c-c}} = 5.64\si{\angstrom} \\
  E_1 = \frac{1^2h^2}{8m_{e^{-}}5.46^2}
\end{gather*}

Using \verb|gather*| (2):
\begin{gather*}
  E_n = \frac{n^2h^2}{8m_{e^{-}}L^2} \quad
  \phantom{E_1 = \frac{1^2h^2}{8m_{e^{-}}5.46^2}} \quad
  L = 4 \times d_{\text{c-c}} = 5.64\si{\angstrom} \\
  \phantom{E_n = \frac{n^2h^2}{8m_{e^{-}}L^2}} \quad
  E_1 = \frac{1^2h^2}{8m_{e^{-}}5.46^2} \quad
  \phantom{L = 4 \times d_{\text{c-c}} = 5.64\si{\angstrom}}
\end{gather*}

Using \verb|alignat*|:
\begin{alignat*}{3}
  E_n = \frac{n^2h^2}{8m_{e^{-}}L^2} & & L = 4 \times d_{\text{c-c}} = 5.64\si{\angstrom} \\
  & \quad E_1 = \frac{1^2h^2}{8m_{e^{-}}5.46^2} \quad
\end{alignat*}

Using an \verb|array|:
\begin{equation*}
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
  \begin{array}{ *{3}{c} }
    \displaystyle E_n = \frac{n^2h^2}{8m_{e^{-}}L^2} & & L = 4 \times d_{\text{c-c}} = 5.64\si{\angstrom} \\
    & \displaystyle E_1 = \frac{1^2h^2}{8m_{e^{-}}5.46^2}
  \end{array}
\end{equation*}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `alignat` environment:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Fontencoding: 7bit -> 8bit
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{alignat*}{2}
E_n = \frac{n^2h^2}{8m_{e^{-}}L^2} & & L=4\times d_{\text{c-c}}=5.64\\
&E_1 = \frac{1^2h^2}{8m_{e^{-}}5.46^2}&
\end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

Note, however, this will place the equation below in between the gap of the two above. It doesn't really center it. Especially, if the equation is long, there will be much space between the first equations.